Can Sports' Playoffs Systems Be Patented Or Some Other Way Protected?
There is not much else, I can think of saying here (sorry)-
I took a higher educational course in higher educational athletic programs management (interestingly, for Physical Education certification) that when shallowly into sports playoffs.
I have also watched endless Real World-Internet Gaming Sports (especially, in FootBall) for 40+-years, so I have fans knowledge of the following as well.
We learned about the most recognizable/popular playoffs structures/features:
Series of games
Vs
Single Games,
per matchup,
Single,
Double
&
Triple
Elimination features,
Snaking (at least that is what comes to mind- think fantasy sports' selecting players process, I cannot think of any other way used, even if they switch between forward & reverse Snaking),
Round Robins
Features
&
Etc. for sports playoffs (sorry, even though I have created & been refining my own sports playoff system, I cannot remember everything I was taught. Great professor & fun for me, so no shot at the professor)
&
reason for facilities are built the ways they are built.
&
Etc.
My playoffs system uses the above & Etc. in vary unique ways. As a result, can Sports' Playoffs Systems be patented?
